# Find a character or group of characters in a string and remove them

Tags: java, string, charat

I am trying to build a program that

1. locates the `@` symbol, then
2. locates the `.edu` part of an educational email address, and finally
3. removes the `@school.edu` section, and return the rest.

I've tried using `charAt`, but I keep receiving an incompatible-types error, and I'm not sure how to remove a section of a string that could be in a different location each time. Any guidance would be welcome.

here is what I have so far:

```
if (UserEmail.charAt(0) == (".edu"))
String UserName = UserEmail.substring(0,//location of @//)

else 
System.out.print(UserEmail + "is not an acceptable email address.
System.out.print("Type your email address.");
UserEmail = kb.nextLine();
```

Comment: Missing parenthesis and quotations in your code block, I think.

Comment: I've improved the formatting and grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `string.replaceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll("@\\S+?\\.edu\\b", "");
```

`\\S+?` will do a non-greedy match of one or more non-space characters.

**Example:**

```
String r = "foo@school.edu bar";
System.out.println(r.replaceAll("@\\S+?\\.edu\\b", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
foo bar
```

Comment: Perfect,thanks! One last question,I keep receiving an "illegal start of expression error at this line:       if (UserEmail.charAt(0) == (".edu"))                                            with this in the output                                                                  "Exception in thread "main"  Uncompilable source code - incomparable types: char and java.lang.String at string.STRING.main(" What could be causing this error?